# Are there any keyboard shortcuts to run a query at SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to run a query/activate the "Run Query" button at [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/new)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're editing a query you can press <kbd>F5</kbd> (which is the same shortcut SQL Server Management Studio uses) to run the query you're currently working on.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the <kbd>F5</kbd> key, I found you can also press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to run your query.  Thanks again, @m0sa!